# if/then/else logic in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file that zips up MS Access 2010 files (file extension .accdb), renames the zip file with the date and time, then moves the zip file to a subfolder called Backups.  The following shows the code so far:

```
 @echo off
 "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Tools\zip.exe" backup.zip *.accdb
 for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%DATE%") do (set thedate=%%g-%%e-%%f)
 for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME:~0,8%") do (set thetime=%%a-%%b-%%c)
 set thetime=%thetime: =0%
 rename backup.zip %thedate%_%thetime%.zip
 move %thedate%_%thetime%.zip .\Backups
 %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe .\Backups
```

This is working fine.  However, I'd like to add a check at the beginning to see if there are any users with open Access files (occurs if there are *.laccdb files) prior to performing the zip operation.  The desired logic is:

1. check if there are any *.laccdb files
2. if there is/are *.laccdb file/s then send user a message to close Access files and abort batch file
3. if no *.laccdb files are found then proceed with the zip operation (as written in the code above)

How do I add this IF/THEN/ELSE type logic to the batch file and how do I check for *.laccdb files?

Comment: please take some time to format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if exist *.laccdb (echo Send the message) else (echo continue the processing)
```

is the full format. Naturally, the `echo` statement can be any series of statements you like, eg.

```
if exist *.laccdb (
 echo Send the message
 goto sendmessage
)
rem the file does not exist, so carry on with the ZIP operation
... your ZIP operation goes in here
goto :eof

:sendmessage
rem put whatever code you want to send the message in here.
goto :eof
```

Note that `goto :eof` is very specific, it requires the colon and means "go to the end of this batch file" It's intrinsic to `cmd` - the label should not be user-declared.

The format of the `if` is also specific.This syntax is required:

```
if condition (
 dothis_if_true
) else (
 dothis_if_false
)
```

The positioning of the parentheses is critical. The first open must be on the same physical line as the `if` (or **do**) and if an else is used then both the preceding `)` and succeeding `(` must occur on the same physical line as the `else`.